# Javascript - faster version - merge/concat two big arrays - unique output

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, unique

Inspired by the article [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items/1584377) I have tested how fast and reliable the different variants are for large number of items.
I also like to make another suggestion to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the example can be tried which function and when faster.
https://dojo.telerik.com/oYuCE/4

The function uniqueArray2 works well and fast on large items.

The jQuery function $ .unique works fast, but only if the items are sorted. Otherwise, duplicates will not be filtered.
Sampel:

```
var arr1 = ['Vijendra', 'Singh'], arr2 = ['Shakya', 'Singh']; 
alert (JSON.stringify ($ .unique (arr1.concat (arr2))));
```

Filters no duplicates, however:

```
var arr1 = ['Vijendra', 'Singh'], arr2 = ['Singh,' Shakya ''];
alert (JSON.stringify ($ .unique (arr1.concat (arr2))));
```

Filters the duplicates.

The function uniqueArray2 works well:

```
function arrayUnique2 (array) {
var tmpArrAss = {};
  $ .each (array, function (key, vs) {
    tmpArrAss [hashCode (vs)] = vs;
  });
  var tmpArr = new Array ();
  $ .each (tmpArrAss, function (key, vs) {
    if (vs.length> 0) {
      tmpArr.push (vs);
    }
  });
  return tmpArr;
}
```

but needs an encoder for long strings, this is here with:

```
function hashCode (s) {
return s.split ("") reduce (function (a, b) {a = ((a << 5) -a) + b.charCodeAt (0); return a & a}, 0);
}
```

solved.
This has the disadvantage that the function works on very long strings.

> arrayUnique2 is 20 time faster.